# Using lsqcurvefit on a matrix

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I trying to use lsqcurvefit on matrix with Pi groups.
I'm VERY new to using Matlab but I have tried to do this:
(xdata=30x5, ydata = 30x1)

```
xdata=[PI2, PI3, PI4, PI5, PI6]'
ydata=PI1
myfun = @(x,xdata) x(1).*(xdata(:,1).^(x(2))).*(xdata(:,2).^(x(3))).*(xdata(:,3).^(x(4))).*(xdata(:,4).^(x(5))).*(xdata(:,5).^(x(6)))+x(7)
x0 = [0; 2.5];
[x] = lsqcurvefit(myfun,x0,xdata,ydata)
```

I get following errors:

Index exceeds the number of array elements (2).

Error in
AnalysisBasic>@(x,xdata)x(1).*(xdata(:,1).^(x(2))).*(xdata(:,2).^(x(3))).*(xdata(:,3).^(x(4))).*(xdata(:,4).^(x(5))).*(xdata(:,5).^(x(6)))+x(7)
(line 83)
myfun = @(x,xdata)
x(1).*(xdata(:,1).^(x(2))).*(xdata(:,2).^(x(3))).*(xdata(:,3).^(x(4))).*(xdata(:,4).^(x(5))).*(xdata(:,5).^(x(6)))+x(7)

Error in lsqcurvefit (line 225)
initVals.F = feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});

Error in AnalysisBasic (line 86)
[x] = lsqcurvefit(myfun,x0,xdata,ydata)

Caused by:
Failure in initial objective function evaluation. LSQCURVEFIT cannot continue.

What do I do wrong?

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwXMQ.png)

Comment: Hi Arch.Eng, welcome to SO! The starting position `x0` has two elements, whereas `myfun` addresses seven coefficients, `x(1)` through `x(7)`. Does something like `x0 = [0;2.5;1;1;1;1;1];` fix the error?

Comment: Thanks you so much!
It worked!!
But is it then possible to give have an argument to make sure that all of the coefficients are within the value of [0;2.5]

Comment: Solved the problem with lb and ub